# How is the Clang's Parallel STL progress?

Tags: c++, c++17, clang++, c++20

According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support), GCC-9 has already implemented the **C++17 Parallel STL** with the linking flag `-ltbb`, but I have not heard information about how Clang focus on that feature or they will never implement that? Can someone tell me about the latest progress, thanks a lot.

Comment: Per [the status page](https://libcxx.llvm.org/cxx1z_status.html) it's a black hole.  Hopefully someone on the clang team will see this and be able to provide some more information.

Comment: Here you can track it: https://reviews.llvm.org/source/pstl/

Comment: libc++ Parallel STL Status: https://libcxx.llvm.org/Status/PSTL.html