# std::execution::par execution policy not providing speedup with std::for_each and std::transform_reduce

Tags: vector, parallel-processing, stl, c++17, matrix-multiplication

I'm trying to do matrix-vector multiplication in parallel in C++ using `std::for_each` and `std::transform_reduce`. I can get the correct answers, however my runtime doesn't change when using `std::par` vs `std::seq` for the execution policy.

For example,

```
std::vector<double> vectorToMultiplyBy(10);
std::vector<std::vector<double>> someMatrix(10, 10);

for (auto it = someMatrix.begin(); it != someMatrix.end(); ++it)
{
   auto i = std::transform_reduce(std::execution::par, it->begin(), it->end(), vectortoMulitplyBy.begin());
}
```

This code provides the same results but the same or slower runtime when `std::execution::par` is exchanged with `std::execution::seq`.

Same idea with `for_each`:

```
std::vector<double> vectorToMultiplyBy(10);
std::vector<std::vector<double>> matrix(10, 10);

std::for_each(std::execution::par, someMatrix.begin(), someMatrix.end(), [](std::vector<double> currentRow)
{

   std::transform_reduce(std::execution::par, currentRow.begin(), currentRow.end(), vectorToMultiplyBy.begin());

});
```

Switching `std::execution::par` with `std::execution::seq` in the above will not change anything if not make things slower. I have tried with up to 32768x32768 matrix (and a 32768x1 vector in that case)

I have confirmed that I am using c++17. I am using g++11 on Apple M1 processor (10 cores).

Timing was done with `std:chrono::high_resolution_clock`.

Comment: Compiler version? Stdlib version? Platform? Core count?

Comment: Your question still lacks version information. Are you sure you're using real g++ and it's not just symlinked to clang? More to the point, are you using libc++? Because if so [it still lacks parallel algorithms](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58732324/636019).

Comment: The version of g++ that is installed and that I am pointing to within Clion settings is not symlinked to Clang. I have libstdc++ installed and no trace of libc++. I am going to try to compile directly with g++ off of the command line and see if that changes anything. I didn't know the info in your link, that seems important 

Edit: when I do `g++ --version`, it shows Apple clang. You might be on to something..

Comment: Ok, so when compiling from CL with my homebrew-installed version of g++ (the one I point to in Clion), the behavior is the same and that one is confirmed to be Homebrew GCC 11.3.0_2) from `--version`. When not specifying the homebrew one, yes it does try to use Clang, which gives errors for the `std::execution::par`, so that means Clion must be using the real GCC.

Comment: 1) please use a monotonic clock instead of `std:chrono::high_resolution_clock` which is not designed for that. 2) M1 processor are big-little ones and most libraries do not support heterogeneous architecture like this one (in fact, this is because they are a pain to support efficiently and not very common). Please check if both big and little cores are running simultaneously and actually even if more than 1 core is used in practice. 3) please check if multiple threads are created. 4) your computation is certainly memory-bound though I expect it to be at least sightly fast with multiple threads

Comment: @clocksw : And are you linking to TBB? libstdc++ will execute everything serially otherwise, even for the parallel execution policies.

Comment: @ildjarn : I wasn't previously, I was not aware that I needed to in order for it to work. That's really useful to know. However, I did install it via brew and passed `-L/opt/homebrew/lib/ -ltbb` during compilation which g++ accepted without complaint, but the `par` policy still provides no speedup and timings match `seq`. Full compilation command: 
`/opt/homebrew/bin/g++-11 -o a.out *.cpp  -std=c++17 -L/opt/homebrew/lib/ -ltbb`

Comment: Also, when I view the activity monitor I never see the thread number increase from 1 for a.out. So still seems to be totally serial. I did switch to using a CPU time clock per @JérômeRichard.

Comment: It's possible/likely that TBB has some threshold before it will bother to parallelize anything. Your test is very small; try making it very large instead. Past that, this is surely some configuration error that is unlikely to be diagnosed here.

Comment: @ildjarn Yeah, I agree. Thanks for all your input.